# jekyll cannot List posts

Tags: jekyll

I am leanging jekyll with the GitHub Pages

I follow the jekyll tutorial step by step, but still cannot list the post. here is my code

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <h2><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and I also set

```
future: true
```

the github page cannot list the post.

My github page:https://v587ygq.github.io/blog.html

My github:https://github.com/v587ygq/v587ygq.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your Jekyll site locally. Looks like there's unknown characters in your post that are causing build errors.

[The raw content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/v587ygq/v587ygq.github.io/master/_posts/2018-02-13-bananas.md) of your blog post on GitHub shows that there are two quotation marks that aren't UTF-8. `fruit �C botanically a berry �C produced`. For some reason those quotation marks aren't the normal ones and are causing build errors. Replace them and the site builds fine.